# The transplant registry guidelines don't play in the gray for a reason

Tags: phrase-meaning

Is 'The transplant registry guidelines don't play in the gray for a reason' the same meaning with 'there is no exception in the transplant registry guidelines'?

Comment: What is the source of the original sentence?

Comment: The title is the line from the drama, The good doctor.

Comment: But guidelines *are* gray. That's what makes them guidelines and not rules. The guideline itself may be clear, but they can be crossed. They are merely cautionary, and the area outside the guideline is the gray area.

Comment: It means that the guidelines have clear definitions (black and white rules) with no room for interpretation (gray areas). Rather than exceptions, not playing in the gray means no arguing opinions about what the rules mean.

Comment: Thank you both for helping me understand more clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly. Although the "The transplant registry guidelines don't play in the gray" part is indeed a creative (if a little callous) way to say "there is no exception in the transplant registry guidelines", there's still that "for a reason" part.

***In the gray*** is a recent-ish English idiom, an extension of the older "black/white" analogy for a strict duality. The term "gray/grey area" to mean ambiguity first appears in Google Books in the late 1940's. If there is a "gray" between black and white, it suggests that a question might have an answer of "maybe" instead of just "yes" or "no".

Suggesting that guidelines "play" is an unwarranted personification. It's callous and a little disingenuous. It's suggesting that the guidelines are acting on their own to decide who gets a transplant and who doesn't, and downplaying the fact that people make those decisions, people with their own unconscious impulses and biases.

Finally there's that "for a reason" part. This goes beyond the lack of compromise in the guidelines. The speaker is telling you that that lack of compromise isn't just made up willy-nilly by some control freaks.  ***There's a reason*** for it: Donor organs are so rare that only people with a medical need should get them, not just the people with the most money who can pay the most.